# Ajax copy data value to clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to copy value of data in ajax success function

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'images/getDownloadUrl/',
    dataType: 'text',
    async: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
    document.execCommand(data);
    }
});
```

How can i copy value of this variable data to clipboard, because this is not work if i only put execCommand?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: How is this ajax call triggered? The browser must be able to attribute the `execCommand` to a user trusted event such as "onClick"

Comment: i found this, but it's not the same problem, because i have problem with ajax

Comment: @bm_i it is triggered with event onClick function that contain this ajax

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can copy your data to clipboard like that :

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'images/getDownloadUrl/',
    dataType: 'text',
    async: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
       let copyFrom = document.createElement("textarea");
        document.body.appendChild(copyFrom);
        copyFrom.textContent = data;
        copyFrom.select();
        document.execCommand("copy");
        copyFrom.remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With `async: false`, it works for me, but only once. The copy works one time, for the first click on the button which does the ajax call. Using multiple buttons also does not work - only the first click on any one button works.

Copy never works with `async: true`.